# Android HttpURLConnection not working with cgi-bin?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, cgi-bin

I have simple code :

```
URL url;
BufferedReader in = null;
HttpURLConnection connection;
InputStream is = null;
InputStreamReader br = null;
setProgressTitle(progress, context.getString(R.string.loading));
setProgressMessage(progress, context.getString(R.string.loading_from_internet));
try {
    url = new URL(urlStr);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(Const.TIMEOUT); 
    is = connection.getInputStream();
    ...
```

If I have urlStr = "http://samlib.ru/w/waliduda_a_a/molochnischituran1.shtml" - all is work fine.
If I use urls like urlStr = "http://samlib.ru/cgi-bin/areader?q=jlist" - I got a error in connection.getInputStream();

**
03-04 15:37:52.459: ERROR/DataReader::loadDataFromInet(17281): Failed loading http://samlib.ru/cgi-bin/areader?q=jlist
03-04 15:37:52.459: ERROR/DataReader::loadDataFromInet(17281): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://samlib.ru/cgi-bin/areader?q=jlist
03-04 15:37:52.459: ERROR/DataReader::loadDataFromInet(17281):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
**

How can I upload data to a similar url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons this might happen. Where I've personally seen it is when I've put in a URL that was subsequently redirected, HttpURLConnection doesn't handle that. I got the same response as you, I hit it with FF and it works fine. Its also possible that some sort of browser sniffing might be done on the recieving side.

Good Luck!

Comment: I thought the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cgi-bin/areader is not found.  Getting an HTTP/404 response code:

```
wget http://samlib.ru/cgi-bin/areader?q=jlist
--2011-03-04 09:03:17--  http://samlib.ru/cgi-bin/areader?q=jlist
Resolving samlib.ru... 81.176.66.171
Connecting to samlib.ru|81.176.66.171|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2011-03-04 09:03:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Correct that then try again.

Comment: I put http://samlib.ru/cgi-bin/areader?q=jlist in my brouser and get text/plain data. In brouser it's works. :

Байки|027|4853
Детектив|002|5671
Детская|029|9399
Драматургия|006|3105
Естествознание|020|6043
Изобретательство|021|1466
История|026|10589
Киберпанк|022|2227
Критика|009|7370
Лирика|003|85249
Литобзор|023|5485
Любовный роман|012|7346
Мемуары|019|7935
Мистика|017|15537
Оккультизм|018|1278
Пародии|031|4411
Переводы|010|6367
Политика|028|5624
Постмодернизм|033|1660
Поэзия|004|261770
Приключения|025|10769
Проза|005|103582